# Правильно ли я написал комментарии в коде?

Tags: java, инспекция-кода

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

class Solution {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
   String date = reader.readLine();// Занесли строку даты "yyyy-MM-dd"

    Date d = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(date);// "yyyy-MM-dd" 
//парсим строку даты "date" и заносим в объект "d"
    SimpleDateFormat a = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy", 
Locale.ENGLISH);// Создаем новый объект "a" для занесения в него нового 
//формата даты

    System.out.println(a.format(d).toUpperCase());// Передаем параметры 
//объекта "d" в "a" и переводим символы в верхний регистр
    }
}
```

Comment: Пожалуй лучше сделать один (или он будет еще одним, но основным) комментарий, а именно, что в целом делает программа. Если я правильно понял, она *читает дату в формате по умолчанию и печатает ее, переведенную в формат Locale.ENGLISH,  в UpperCase*

Comment: Написал правильно, в смысле без ошибок. Беда в том, что ни один из этих комментариев не нужен. Комментарии не должны повторять код другими словами, они не для этого. Такие комментарии даже вредны.